# Bandpass filter after frequency domain fft

Tags: python, python-3.x

I plotted the frequency domain (`Fourier spectrum`) of an `ECG` signal.
There is a high `0 Hz` peak (baseline wander) and high `50 Hz` peak (net power). So I would like to filter with a band pass `5 - 49 Hz`.
*raw_data = data (y-axis) and t = time (x-axis)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

## Raw data
raw_data = raw_data['data'][:300010, Channel - 1] # 1 (-1) is channel of ECG
fs = 1000 # Hz
tt_time = len(raw_data) / fs # total measure time (s)
t = np.arange(0, tt_time, 1 / fs) # Calculate time

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(t, raw_data)

## fourier spectrum
frsp = np.fft.fft(raw_data) / len(raw_data) # fourier spectrum
frsp = frsp[range(int(len(raw_data) / 2))] # half of fourier for y axis

v = np.arange(int(tt_time * fs / 2)) # number of values
frqs = v / tt_time # frequencies for x axis

## Plot frequency domain spectrum
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(frqs, abs(frsp))

## Bandpass filter
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = .5 * fs
    low = lowcut/nyq
    high = highcut/nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low,high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(raw_data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b,a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b,a,raw_data)
    return y

lowcut = 5.0
highcut = 49.0

## Plot filtered signal
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
y = butter_bandpass_filter(t, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5)
plt.plot(t, y)
```

After trying this code, it doesn't filter like it needs to be filtered. I know I need a band pass but I don't know how to apply it to my code and data. Who can help me? Thank you in advance :)

First 150 seconds output example:
[image]

Comment: Order in the filters plays a major role. Bigger the number, the more perpendicular line would be. Can you change it and observe the change. Go through this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Butterworth_Filter_Orders.svg . And also please add tyour output also.

Comment: @Solen'ya thank you for the tips. I tried different orders but didn't do better in results. I also added the output.

Comment: can you post data for the variable 't'?

Comment: @mkfin see updated question post

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve). Right now it seems you are using `butter_bandpass_filter()` on a `np.arange()`... so no 50 Hz oscillation, there will be a 0 freq, but you cannot expect it to look anything like your first plot.

Comment: @norok2 see updated question post. How can I apply a bandpass filter on np.arange()?

Comment: What happens if you replace `y = butter_bandpass_filter(t, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5)` with `y = butter_bandpass_filter(raw_data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5)` ?

Comment: @norok2 you are great! It works properly now yeaj :) thank you! Although I have another q: Do you know why I need to write down 3x order = 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
y = butter_bandpass_filter(t, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5)
```

with

```
y = butter_bandpass_filter(raw_data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5)
```

Thanks to **Norok2** (see comments)